Invalid access token, ... does not contain required scopes. - scope issue for S2S Zoom GraphQL query
I want to list all Zoom cloud recordings. I used to do in using Zoom's API. But now I think it would be easier to use graphQL. Also instead of General App, I thought I would create Server to Server OAuth application. So I created one, I can get Access token but
when I try to do any graphQL query, I get
"Invalid access token, users field does not contain required scopes."


I cannot get help from Zoom because I did not pay for developer support.
There is no response to my question on Zoom developers forum
so I hope someone here would be able to help me

When I get the access token I get list of scopes and the userMeetingRecordings is really not there. But this scope “cloud_recording:read:list_user_recordings:admin” was added.
I have created

Account-level app
Server-To-Server OAuth
I am the owner of the account of Zoom Workspace Pro account.
I have just created new app with the same result
the same result gives me

my php code
Postman
Zooms graphQL playground - https://nws.zoom.us/graphql/playground


the query status code is 200

My query is like this
{
   userMeetingRecordings(userId: "me",first:10) {
        edges {
            id
            uuid
            recordingFiles{
                id
            }
        }
        pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            cursor
        }
    }
}

but even the sample one from Zoom documentation does not work. The same issue with the scope.
{
  users(first:100){
    edges{
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    department
    }
  }
}

What I find strange is that the error message is “Invalid access token, userMeetingRecordings field does not contain required scopes.” but when I get the access token I also get list of scopes. I believe that is is a list of scopes I have access to. But this list does not contain userMeetingRecordings .
NOTE that when creating the application I selected ALL possible scopes related to recordings.

When I get the access token I get list of scopes and the userMeetingRecordings is really not there. But this scope “cloud_recording:read:list_user_recordings:admin” was added.
Is anybody there who would be able to help me to make graphQL work?
UPDATE
User permissions set up

UPDATE2
Zoom for developers setting


have you Enable the Server-to-Server OAuth role in your Account?
Enable the Server-to-Server OAuth role

In the Zoom web portal, the administrator must go to User Management > Roles > Role Settings > Advanced features and select the View and Edit check boxes for Server-to-Server OAuth app. See Using role management for details.

I don't know how helpful the graphQL error messages are.  But with the rest API, missing scopes are clearly reported in the error response.
With the rest API, if you are not getting scope error messages, then the error is usually account configuration related.
request with missing scopes
request:
GET https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/recordings 

response:
400 Bad Request
error:{
  "code":4711,
  "message":"Invalid access token, does not contain scopes
        [cloud_recording:read:list_user_recordings,
         cloud_recording:read:list_user_recordings:admin]."
}

response after adding required scopes:
200 OK
{
  "from":"2024-07-02",
  "to":"2024-07-03",
  "page_count":1,
  "page_size":10,
  "total_records":10,
  "next_page_token":"",
  "meetings":[...]
}


Hi Ben, the role settings was not turned on. But turning on did not help :-(
